# Flutter Firestore, convert list of maps to something useable

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So I am trying to get an List of maps from firebase, which looks like this
[image]

I want to get the data and put it into a list where I could, for example search the right map by title and get the description out of it, but I struggle to get the architecture for it right.

I get the data like this

```
  final _ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('AllHabits')
        .snapshots()
        .map((query) =>
        query.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()['test']
            .map((testDoc)=> HabitInfo.fromDoc(testDoc))).toList());
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: _ref,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return Loading();
          final test = snapshot.data;
          print(test);
          return Container();
        });
  }
```

And use a model

```
class  HabitInfo {
  final String description;
  final String title;

  HabitInfo({required this.description, required this.title});

  factory HabitInfo.fromDoc(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> doc) {
    final data = doc.data()!;
    return HabitInfo(
      description: data['description'],
      title: data['title'],
    );
    // calendarEvents: data['calendarEvents']);
  }
}
```

When I halt I see the data looks like this, but also a runtime error

**type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>'**

[image]

So my question is, how can I store this data in my model, so I can use it
for search (Where title = test, I want to get description for that) And how do I
Solve this runtime error

Comment: So Victors suggestion fixed the runtime, but still can't get the type right

Answer (score 0):

**Solving the runtime error below:**

> type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of
> type 'DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>'

Change this code below:

```dart
   factory HabitInfo.fromDoc(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> doc) {
     ...
   }
```

to:

```dart
   factory HabitInfo.fromDoc(Map<String, dynamic> doc) {
     ...
   }
```

The error occurs because you're getting the field value in this line below:

```dart
doc.data()['test']
```

And it will return a `Map` based on the database structure in the screenshot,  and not a `DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>` as defined in the `HabitInfo.fromDoc()` method.

**Update:**

You can make an update to the `StreamBuilder` code like this:

```dart
return StreamBuilder<List<HabitInfo>>(
        stream: _ref,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return Loading();
          final test = snapshot.data;
    
          test.forEach((habitInfo) {
            print(habitInfo.title);
            print(habitInfo.description);
          });
    
          return Container();
});
```

Specifying the type as the `List<HabitInfo>` in the `StreamBuilder` makes `snapshot.data` of type `List<HabitInfo>`.

Comment: how should i read data with this change then? Since  'data' isn't defined for the type 'Map'.

Comment: read it using this `[]` operator directly. E.g `doc['description']`

Comment: Ahh gotcha, that fixed it. Any idea how I can use this object value I get from snapshot.data? So (for example) if I search for the title I can get the description? Should I convert it from Object?

Comment: Since i am getting Object, not map

Comment: Could you rephrase that? What are you trying to do and what part of the code are you referring to?

Comment: My snapshot.data is now getting Object. How can I use the data stored in it? Like print out 1st maps title and description?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233716/discussion-between-victor-eronmosele-and-s3v3ns).

Comment: replied in discussion